# Java, add to jpanel from another class to jframe

Tags: java, swing

I have a two classes that looks like following:

```
public class Board extends JFrame {

private JFrame frame;

public Board() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(this.createContentPane());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel createContentPane (){
    
    JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));

    JPanel red = createSquareJPanel(Color.red, 50);
    JPanel blue = createSquareJPanel(Color.blue, 50);
  
    mainPanel.add(red);
    mainPanel.add(blue);

    totalGUI.add(mainPanel);
    totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
    return totalGUI;
}

private JPanel createSquareJPanel(Color color, int size)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(color, size);
    return rect;
}
}

public class Rectangle extends JPanel {

    public Rectangle(Color color, int size) {
        this.setBackground(color);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));

    }
}
```

The problem is that when the method "createSquareJPanel" creates the Rectangle object, only the first element appears of 2 in the gridlayout. So i only see the red rectangle.

If i put the code from the Rectangle class inside the createSquareJPanel and create a JPanel inside here, then it is working as expected. I dont understand why only one element appears with this code.

Comment: 1) Don't extend JFrame. There is no need for the Board class to extend any object. 2) Don't call the class Rectangle. There already is a class by that name in the JDK so it is confusing. 3). Code works fine for make. Make the above changes and delete all the class files from your project to make sure you don't have any old files lying around.

Comment: 1) and 2) Did not change anything. I'm not sure how i delete all the class files from my project.

Comment: How do you delete any file from a directory on your machine?

Comment: Ok i tried that. Unfortunately, this did not change anything.

Comment: Don't know what to say. First of all update you code to reflect the changes made so people don't keep making the same suggestions. The answer below repeated one of my suggestions.

Comment: (1-) @Busquets_90, *but i have a function inside Rectangle that i did thought not matters but when i delete it everything is working, looks like following: public int getY()* - the point of posting code is to post the EXACT code you are testing. It is a waste of our time  otherwise. Yes that is an obvious problem, but its only obvious if we see the code. How else did you think I tested the code when I stated it worked for me? I copied the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i agree with you. Why does it not work with custom functions like "public int getY()"? I didn't even use the function.

Comment: The methods getX() and getY() are defined in the Component class. By overriding those methods you lose the default behaviour. This is something you learn from experience. I've done it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. I have re-write it to test but it's quite a clone. https://github.com/amaurylrd/stackoverflow-jpanel

Also, the class Rectangle should not be in the Board file but I think you but it here for the post. I wonder why this class is extending JFrame but also have a JFrame attribute. Btw those are squares, right ?

I want you to see that totalGUI is almost useless too, you can use the default contentPane or the mainPanel you created, it works fine alone. The fact that the default layout is FlowLayout.

Comment: A JPanel is opaque by default. There is no need to invoke the setOpaque(...) method.

Comment: Don't post the code on github. Just post the code in the forum for everybody to see.

Comment: I have tested the default opacity for JPanel, you are right it is opaque by default. I must be confusing with JLabel. I have change my answer to avoir misleadings.

Comment: I'll do both, but the point was to show the code.

Comment: Thanks for the code, that is working for me also. But the Rectangle class is not inside Board file like you mentioned. When i change it to a separate file it is not longer working. So i guess the issue is about this. I should have been clear about this at the beginning

Comment: I have just commited to match what you say, and it works perfectly fine with the class Rectangle in a separate file.

Comment: Well i found my issue, thanks for you help. I don't understand why but i have a function inside Rectangle that i did thought not matters but when i delete it everything is working, looks like following:     public int getY() {
        return Y_COORDINATE;
    }, It seems to be something with the name "getY" when i change that to another name everything is ok